# Observe WiFi / 3G changes

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

Is it possible to observe when the user switch between WiFi and cellular data (3G/4G)?

Maybe something in Reachability, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I think is import CoreTelephony and observe CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification and then switch over that like this:

```
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let radio = networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology

guard let currentRadio = radio else {
   print("No radio info available")
   return
}

switch currentRadio {
   case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA: //3.5G "T-Mobile 4G"
       print("This is 4G / LTE")
   case CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD, //3.5G "Verizon 3G"
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB:
      print("This is 3G")
   case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS,
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x
        CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge:
      print("This is 2G")
   default:
      print("Unknown cellular network type")
   }
```

If you listen for that notification while also using standard Reachability, you can use this switch to get cell network type. You will need currentReachabilityStatus to independently check for a WiFi connection. As far as I am aware, in Swift you need to set up a bridging header to use Apple's Reachability class but there are Swift implementations available as well on github.

Comment: Thanks, so what I was looking for is to combine your answer with @Arun 's answer, and to observe currentReachabilityStatus

Answer (score 2):

Yes Reachability provide you with type of network connected. It gives 3 different status - Not Connected to internet, Connected to Wifi, Connected to Mobile Data.

```
NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No Connectivity to Internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //Connected via WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //Connected  via Mobile Data
}
```